# How does the dictionary know what I am talking about?

Tags: python, dictionary

In this code on line 20 we see "total_amount += menu[food]". How does the program know that I am trying to add the price from my menu variable and not the words "Baja Taco", "Bowl", etc. Like lets say each item in the diciontary was something like "baja taco": [4.00, yummy, salty, sweet, crunch]. How would I call just the 3rd key in "baja taco".

```python
menu = {
    "Baja Taco": 4.00,
    "Burrito": 7.50,
    "Bowl": 8.50,
    "Nachos": 11.00,
    "Quesadilla": 8.50,
    "Super Burrito": 8.50,
    "Super Quesadilla": 9.50,
    "Taco": 3.00,
    "Tortilla Salad": 8.00
}

total_amount = 0

while True:
    try:
        food = input("Item: ").title()
        if food in menu:
            total_amount += menu[food]
            print("Total: $", end="")
            print("{:.2f}".format(total_amount))
    except EOFError:
        print()
        pass
```

Comment: _How would I call just the 3rd key in "baja taco"_ `menu["baja taco"][2]`

Comment: FYI, using a named tuple rather than a list for the attributes would greatly increase the readability and reduce the risk of bugs.

Comment: _How does the program know that I am trying to add the price from my menu variable and not the words "Baja Taco", "Bowl", etc_ Because `menu[food]` gives you the dict _value_, not the _key_.  And in your dict, the prices are _values_.

Answer (score 1):

dictionaries use key-value pairs. In your example, when you put menu["Baja Taco"], it knows that the value given to that item in the dictionary is 4.00 because you've told it that in this line:

```
menu = {
    "Baja Taco": 4.00,
```

if the dictionary actually had a list for the value, like you asked, then you would get the list back and you would need to use list indexing to access the value you want. so this dictionary:

```
menu = {
    "Baja Taco": [4.00, 'yummy', 'salty', 'sweet', 'crunch']
}
```

when called like this:

```
menu["Baja Taco"]
```

would give this:
`[4.00, 'yummy', 'salty', 'sweet', 'crunch']`

you would need to add an index to access different items. So for example:

```
menu["Baja Taco"][0]
```

would return `4.0`